# CodeIgniter - Pagination conflicting with delete

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have pages of data, pulled from a database. I need to be able to delete a record on the page which is displaying all of the rows of data.

So customers/index displays all of the rows. Controller:

```
public function index($page = 'customer_list', $title = 'Customer List') {      
    $this->exists($page);

    $data['customer'] = $this->customers_model->get_customers();
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['content'] = 'content/'.$page.'.php';

    $this->load->view('frame/grab', $data);
}

public function delete() {  
    $this->customers_model->delete_customer();

    $this->index();
}
```

It uses this model function:

```
public function get_customers() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //Config for pagination
    $config['base_url'] = '**cant post links**/customers/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('customers')->num_rows();
    //Rows per page
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    //Number of links shown to navigate
    $config['num_links'] = 20;

    //Initializes the pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $query = $this->db->get('customers', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here is my view:

```
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-header">
            <h2 class="floatl"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
            <a class="add-new floatr" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>customers/add"><h4>Add New Customer &raquo;</h4></a>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="sort-container">
            Sort by:
            <ul class="sort">
                <li><a href="#">ID Ascending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ID Descending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">First Name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Last Name</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php
        //Creates the template for which the table is built to match
        $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'          => '<table class="data-table">
                                                    <tr class=\'tr-bgcolor table-header\'>
                                                        <td>#</td>
                                                        <td>First Name</td>
                                                        <td>Last Name</td>
                                                        <td>Edit</td>
                                                        <td>Delete</td>
                                                    </tr>',

                        'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
                        'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                        'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
                        'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                        'row_start'           => '<tr class="tr-bgcolor">',
                        'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                        'cell_start'          => '<td>',
                        'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                        'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                        'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                        'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
                        'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                        'table_close'         => '</table>'
                      );

        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);

        //Creates table rows from the rows of data in the db which were created as the customer array
        foreach ($customer as $row) :
            $this->table->add_row(
                $number = array('data' => $row->rec_num, 'class' => 'center'),
                $row->last_name,
                $row->first_name,
                $edit = array('data' => '[ <a href="#">Edit</a> ]'),
                $edit = array('data' => '[ <a href="'.base_url().'customers/delete/'.$row->rec_num.'">Delete</a> ]')
            );
        endforeach;

        //Creates the table based on the rows determined above
        echo $this->table->generate();

        //Creates page links
         echo $this->pagination->create_links();
        ?>
    </div>
```

So I'm thinking that the pagination is getting in the way, because when I click the delete link, it sends it to customers/delete/#. So it deletes the record, as it should, but the displayed results are varied because I believe the pagination is off setting the displayed rows by the number in the URL (Which is actually just the ID of the row).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does `delete_customer()` work without having a number passed to it?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to post my delete function in the model. It just uses the 3rd segment of the URL to grab the ID for the row. so if it's customers/delete/5, it will delete the 3rd row in the db with that number. It's also being used to offset the records being displayed in the table, which is the problem. Just not sure how this is usually handled I guess.

Comment: The model shouldn’t refer to anything other than the database and the variables it’s given. So in the Controller you should call `$this->customers_model->delete_customer($id);`, then use `delete_customer($id)` in the model as the ID, rather than relying on the URL from the model. You can fetch the ID using the Controller method `function delete($id)` rather than `function delete()`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll be sure to adjust my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is make redirect after deleting row in db to the index page:

```
public function delete() {  
    $this->customers_model->delete_customer();
    redirect('customers/index');
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do what I needed. Wasn't sure of how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: it is simple way. The best way is to redirect to the same page and check if this page exist or no then to previous. I do not know how to do this. Maybe someone can give an idea ?